# Collapse responsive nav when clicking link

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, nav

I'm trying to get my responsive navigation to collapse when clicking a navigation item (link).

This is my navigation:

```
<nav class="nav">
 <ul>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#amenities">Amenities</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#residences">Residences</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#neighborhood">Neighborhood</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#availability">Availability</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><li class="btn login">Login</li></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()"><li class="nav-toggle"></li></a>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Here's how the responsive nav gets expanded:

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What isn't working? A jsfiddle would probably be useful in this case...

Comment: I want to remove the "responsive" class from the nav when clicking on a list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses.
This is what I was looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li.nav-item a, .logo").click(function(){
   $("nav").removeClass("responsive");
  });
});
```

Now the "responsive" class gets removed when clicking on a navigation item or the logo, so my navigation returns to collapsed mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're mixing old school list tags with the modern Nav because you don't need them.

If you want the menu to collapse upon selection you can use this neat technique:

```
<nav style="position:absolute; left:20px; top:50px;">

<div onclick="TheBox.removeAttribute('open');">

<details id="TheBox"><summary>Choices</summary>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">Home</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">About</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">Products</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">Services</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">Contact</a>

</div></details></nav>
```

Comment: Please change last line from</div></details></nav> to </details></div></nav>. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to hide the navigation when the toggle link is clicked. If so, I would do the following. Note that your `<a>` tags were outside the `<li>` tags, I've moved them inside.

```
<nav id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#amenities">Amenities</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#residences">Residences</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#neighborhood">Neighborhood</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#availability">Availability</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="btn login"><a href="#" target="_blank">Login</a></li>
  <li class="nav0item"><a href="javascript:collapseNav();">Toggle</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

I would target by ID and not class, and set the display to none.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function collapseNav() {
  document.getElementById('nav').style.display = "none";}
</script>
```

Since your toggle is on a `<li>` inside the nav, your navigation menu (and the toggle) will be hidden when activated. So, I'd make a way to show it again. You could, for instance, add this function in your JS.

```
function showNav() {
  document.getElementById('nav').style.display = "block";}
```

And then add a link somewhere for the user to show the menu again.

```
<button onclick="showNav();" >Show Menu</button>
```

If you go that route, I'd also hide the Show Menu button by default by adding `id="shownav" style="display: none;"` to hide it initially. And then have your collapseNav function also show the button:

```
document.getElementById('shownav').style.display = "block";
```